# How to use Regex in pandas DataFrame with Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I try to replace only one caracter of a string in a pandas columns. Concretly, I want to replace . by - in the "Date" columns

Here is my script :

```
import pandas as pd

number = {"date": [2002.04, 2002.05], "team": ["a", "b"]}
number_pandas = pd.DataFrame(number)
number_pandas

number_pandas.date.replace(".", "-")
```

Here is the output :

```
0    2002.04
1    2002.05
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

It does not work. Maybe you can help with Regex.

Comment: `number_pandas['date'].astype(str).str.replace(".", "-", regex=False)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the column data to that of type `str` first, and then use a mere string replacement with

```py
number_pandas['date'].astype(str).str.replace(".", "-", regex=False)
```

A Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> number = {"date": [2002.04, 2002.05], "team": ["a", "b"]}
>>> number_pandas = pd.DataFrame(number)
>>> number_pandas['date'].astype(str).str.replace(r".", "-", regex=False)
0    2002-04
1    2002-05
Name: date, dtype: object
>>>
```